# Я хочу чтобы бот запомнил одно значение, другое, а потом сравнил их

Tags: python, telebot, бот

```
import telebot
import random

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['roll'])
def roll(messsage):
    zxc = str(random.randrange(100))
    bot.reply_to(message, zxc)


bot.polling()
```

Даже в голову не приходит, как сделать что-то подобное

Comment: из кода не ясно что именно вам требуется, уточните детали.

Answer (score 0):

Пороробуйте после токена объявить к примеру список data = []
В него можно будет помещать и возвращать значения когда это потребуеться из под любой ф-ции.